# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '||'

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to figure out what is wrong with my code. In the console I keep on getting "expected expression, got '||'" but I've got no idea why. Can anyone enlighten me?

Thanks

```js
  if (isNaN(value)) || value < 0 || value > 9 {
    result.innerHTML = `<p class="result">${text[0]}</p>`;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have misplaced parentheses on your `if` statement.

Replace this:

```
 if (isNaN(value)) || value < 0 || value > 9
```

With this:

```
 if (isNaN(value) || value < 0 || value > 9)
```